# Screen scraping through AJAX and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to scrape a screen using AJAX and javascript. How is this possible?

Need to scrape this : **http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?ascend_header=1&clienttype=dotcom&cntry_code=us&language=english&tracknumbers=776812461212825**

I had used the technique given in w3school.com, but it's showing "access denied." Why is the "access denied" showing? Please solve my problem..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are screen scraping by trying to access the FedEx URL directly from your Javascript/website on your own domain, that is your problem. If you really want to do this, the easiest way would be to make an AJAX call to a script somewhere in your domain and have it make the tracking request for you.

[Check out this information on creating proxies.](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Building on Beau Simensen answer, you could make an Ajax call to your own domain:

```
Ajax.Request("http://mydomain.com/proxy.php?url=http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?ascend_header=1&clienttype=dotcom&cntry_code=us&language=english&tracknumbers=776812461212825");
```

The proxy.php file would just make a CURL request (or something else) to the url parameter provided and return its result, this way you can access all sites on your local domain through that proxy.php.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax/XMLHttpRequest calls are restricted to a same-site policy for security reasons; you can't use them to directly load remote sites. Firefox 3.1 [apparently](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) added support for cross-site requests, but I haven't heard if any other browsers jumped.